# Storing lots of messages in C++ namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a little program that basically prompt questions to user, read the answer, check its validity, and so on, until the creation of an RPG character is fully performed. I rapidly got several classes, each of them related to a bunch of messages to store.

My question is : what is the best way of storing these messages ?

My first (and dirty) try was to have a single file messages.hpp :

```
namespace M
{
   string const message1("what's your name ?");
   // + many others
}
```

but as many classes depended on this file, any tiny change to it implied very long compilation time.

So in order to redistribute the messages, I wanted to include the relevant messages as static members of the classes that needed them, but I found it spoiled a bit readability of my class header. So I was wandering : can I create a subnamespace in a class that will be a message collector like this :

```
// monster.h
class Monster
{
// members and methods declared here
};

namespace Monster::Messages
{
    string const message1("what's your name ?");
    // + others messages only used by Monster
}
```

and could possibly be used like this :

```
// monster.cpp
Monster::Monster()
{
   cout << Messages::message1 << endl;
}
```

But then, I wondered :

- will all the messages of `Monster::messages` be copied for each instance of the class `Monster` ?
- will all the messages of `Monster::messages` be copied in all files including `monster.hpp` (static linkage) ?
- Are the messages considered members, static members, or not members at all in `Monster` ?
- What happen if I use the `static` keyword in Monster::messages, will
  it have the signification of static linkage or static member ?

And of course : is it bad practice ? Is there a clever way ?

Comment: Is this not what a database is for?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the best practice is to store all those data information in external data file of your game.

I'm going to provide you some benefits of doing so:

- Code more clear and light.
- Little modifications on data game can be achieved even without compile the binary. That is very important for those data parameters which have to be tested and each time you change the value you have to run the game to see all side effects. (For example some parameters about monster health, damage, GUI position, etc...). In this way the test phase does not require to compile the binary again and it's faster.
- Allow other game developers to easily modify game parameters. For example for those persons in the team who are not programmers.
- Allow easily to modify game data without change the design in the code. For example let's suppose after two years your game becomes to be very popular and you want to translate it in several languages in order to get more users. In case all those data are embedded in the code, you should re-design and modify your code and, maybe the thing more important, the person who can do that work is only you because only you have the access and the knowledge of the code. In the other case (when the data are stored in external files), more person can easily access and upgrade your game.

---

How do you can achieve this procedure could be another question on SO, but there are several choices.

For example you can create a unique huge file (that implies some smart tricks, especially for performance reasons) or you can distribute the data parameters in several files.
So your game will have a phase of *loading* in which the data are read from the disk (as almost all the other games).

Moreover you should think (if you need it) a method in order to crypt those files and avoid game-users can modify them.

Comment: *cough* SQLite *cough*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, As I've said there are a lots of way in order to do that. The database is easiest and maybe most efficient choice in general. In the specific case there could be different choices. It depends on the licences, the amount of data, his programming skills, etc...

Comment: So SQLite could be a solution. What about MySQL ? What is the simplest for a beginner in database ?

Comment: @Funky In you case I'm pretty sure *SQLite* is the best option. MySQL need a DBMS, so when you distribute your game you need a server process. Moreover MySQL is an open source license. SQLite, on the other hand, is an "embedded database" and (if I am not wrong) you should not have license problem because is public domain.